# .NET 6 DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds() is throwing an error

Tags: c#

When I run this code in a XUnit test class:

```
 var x = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1645614860415);
 Assert.IsType<DateTimeOffset>(x);
```

I have an exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131502
  Message=Valid values are between -62135596800 and 253402300799, inclusive. Arg_ParamName_Name
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(Int64 seconds)
   at Test_Lib.Unit.....
```

I have checked the value 1645614860415 and it is a valid number.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Well, because 1645614860415 is larger than 253402300799, obviously. Most likely you are confusing seconds with milliseconds.

Comment: Secondary note: the assertion is pointless. There is no way it could possibly fail.

Comment: The number is 52182 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have checked the value 1645614860415 and it is a valid number.

Not as a number of *seconds* since the Unix epoch, it's not - at least not for `DateTimeOffset`.

1645614860415 seconds is over 50,000 years... whereas 1645614860415 *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch is today.

So basically you want `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`.

One good site for testing this is [epochconverter.com](https://epochconverter.com). It allows you to enter seconds, milliseconds, microseconds or nanoseconds - *and tells you which one it thinks you meant*. So with the value you provided, it says: "Assuming that this timestamp is in **milliseconds**" (and then shows a recent time).